# Compare values in two rows fo specific column

Tags: awk

I would like to print the lines of file based on a condition with respect the previous line. I would like to implement the following condition:

> If the key (field 1 and field2) between the current line and the previous line is identical **and** the difference between field 8 and field 8 of the previous line is bigger than 1, print the current line **and** append the difference.

**Input file:**

```
47329,39785,2,12,10,351912.50,2533105.56,170.93,1
47329,39785,3,6,7,351912.82,2533105.07,170.89,1
47329,39785,2,12,28,351912.53,2533118.81,172.91,1
47329,39785,3,6,20,351913.03,2533117.41,170.93,1
47329,39797,2,12,10,352063.14,2533117.84,170.66,1
47329,39797,3,6,7,352064.11,2533119.32,170.64,1
47329,39797,2,12,28,352062.77,2533104.67,173.63,1
47329,39797,3,6,20,352063.50,2533107.10,170.69,1
```

**Expected output file:**

```
47329,39785,2,12,28,351912.53,2533118.81,172.91,1,1.98
47329,39797,2,12,28,352062.77,2533104.67,173.63,1,2.94
```

Lines 3 and 4 have an identical key (`47329,39785`) and the difference of the values in fields 8 is `172.91-170.93=1.98`, so we print line 4. An identical reasoning goes for lines 6 and 7

**attempt:**

```
awk -F, 'NR%2{ab = $1 FS $2} ab == ob && $8 - O8 > 1; {ob = ab; O8 = $8}'
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Could you show the exact ?

Comment: Again I do not understand your output. You mention every second row of the 4 rows (i.e. you compare record 2 vs record 4), but you print record3 (in the case of `47329,39785`) ... This is very confusing. Could you please tell us what you want to compare of the 4 rows, and what you want to print of the 4 rows.

Comment: This question is also identical to your question you asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176279/compare-values-in-multiple-rows-in-single-column) ...

Comment: Also this one looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60183263/1839439

Comment: Gents, i changed a little my question hope it is more clear now. Tks for your support.

Comment: @kvantour, yes please, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @kvantour, Tks a lot, this works like i want, only, please can u add one extra column with diff value found.. Tks a lot

Comment: @OXXO I have updated your question, could you review it?

Comment: `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}(k == $1 FS $2) && ($8-f8 > 1){print $0,$8-f8}{ k=$1 FS $2; f8 = $8 }`

Comment: You say line 4 should be a match, but line 3 is a previous match. Difference between $8 of line 4 and 3 is negative, does it need to be greater than one in both directions? Please [review and edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185425/compare-values-in-two-rows-fo-specific-column/60954760#) your example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with this script, tested on gawk v5.0.0

```
BEGIN{
    FS=","
}
{
    if (NR == 1)
    {
        key1 = $1
        key2 = $2
        field = $8
        # when on first record, there's nothing to compare with
        next
    }
    if ($1 == key1)
    {
        if ($2 == key2)
        {
            if ($8 - field > 1)
            {
                print $0, $8-field
                # uncomment following line to print line match number
                # print "("NR")",$0, $8-field
            }
        }
    }
    # assign for next iteration
    key1 = $1
    key2 = $2
    field = $8
}
```

tested on your input, found:

```
$ awk -f script.awk test.txt
47329,39785,2,12,28,351912.53,2533118.81,172.91,1 2.02
47329,39797,2,12,28,352062.77,2533104.67,173.63,1 2.99
```

Matches line 3 and 7.

Comment: @OXXO, if the code works fine and solves your answer, please consider to accept my answer. Have a read at [what can you do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)